# Woocommerce - Append a recommended product at the start of the product loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On product archive page, i filter results according to certain attributes. Everything works well with filtering but additionally i want to show 2 of results at the start of the loop which belongs to certain category as recommended products. The idea is show the correct results but also promoting first 2 products of a given category by showing them at first.

Current situation:
url: http://localhost/woo/product-category/clothing/?filter_color=blue

Results: 10 blue, clothing category products.

What i want to do is, if there are any product also has jean (blue color) category, showing these at most 2 blue jean/clothing products at the start of the loop. I will be having 12 products with the same filtered url. Later i will add different badge to these 2 items to hightlight them.

woocommerce/layouts/category.php

```
            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    
                    the_post();

                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                     *
                     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                }
            }

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

funtions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', function(){

    if ( is_product_category() && is_main_query() ) :

        wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' );

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post__in'  => array( 12, 13 ), // Your product IDs
        );

        $sticky = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ($sticky->have_posts()) :
            $sticky->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile; 

        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

woocommerce/layouts/category.php

```
woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {

    do_action( 'woocommerce_product_loop_sticky' );

    while ( have_posts() ) {

        the_post();

        /**
        * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
        *
        * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
        */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
}

woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

funtions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_loop_sticky', function(){

    wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        //'post__in'  => array( 12, 13 ), // Your product IDs
        //OR
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'advert_tag',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( 18 ), // Your product catedory ID
            )
        ),
    );

    $sticky = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($sticky->have_posts()) :
        $sticky->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_postdata();

} );
```

Or you can use only this code (without changing the loop in the category template) in the functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_stiky');
function woocommerce_shop_loop_stiky(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        //'post__in'  => array( 12, 13 ), // Your product IDs
        //OR
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'advert_tag',//
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( 18 ), // Your product catedory ID
            )
        ),
    );

    $sticky = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($sticky->have_posts()) :
        $sticky->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_postdata();
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_stiky' );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried it but didn't work. It showed the same items vertically (full width). I added some details. Possible to give a little more push?

Comment: Hello! You're welcome! I have changed my answer. Check a new recommendation.

Comment: It would help if you used tax_query. See an example upper.